# Permanently change HTML text using jQuery UI Modal Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have a few tables on an HTML page in which I need to make the content inside the `<td>` tags editable using a jQuery UI Modal Form, meaning that using the jQuery UI Modal Form one should be able to **permanently** edit the content.

For example:

**HTML:**

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="name">John Doe</td>
    <td id="number">999 999 9999</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button id="edit">Edit</button>
```

**The Modal Form:**

```
<div id="edit-form" title="Edit Info">
  <form>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Contact Info</legend>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Name</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="cName" id="cName" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Number</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="cNumber" id="cNumber" /></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

**Javascript/jQuery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function () {
    var name = $("#cName"),
        number = $("#cNumber");

    $("#edit")
        .button()
        .click(function () {
            $("#edit-form").dialog("open");

    $("#edit-form").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 'auto',
        width: 'auto',
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Apply": function () {
                document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = name.val();
                document.getElementById('number').innerHTML = number.val();
                $(this).dialog("close");
            },
            Cancel: function () { $(this).dialog("close"); }
        }
    });
});

</script>
```

However, this only changes the HTML text **temporarily**. If I reload the page, the old text is back.

How can I implement this so that the new text replaces the old text (i.e. it written to the file)? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Then you need to _store_ it somewhere like a database, cookies, localStorage, etc.

Comment: How do I do that? How do I write it to the original file?

Comment: store it to a database is the "best" way to store it permanently. cookies and localStorage can be cleared. so set up a database and insert/update the text.

Comment: It is just a simple HTML page. I should not be using any Database.

Comment: @taa this is not a simple HTML .. it might be that you form will have only one textfield but it does have dynamic data so you must use DB

Comment: Or you could post your edit to the server and let some server side script edit your HTML file. But I would not recommend that. Why do you not want to use a database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not change the html file from javascript. Not even if it's on the same computer and you use file:// schema. You'll need to store the data in a DB, and display the html dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to store that modified data into a cookie and read its content when you load the page. So you store data in a cookie created and managed by you on JS side.

Link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie

However, to use a cookie for this is not recommended. The best practise is to store data in a DB as everybody suggested you before.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think it's a good idea to store it in a cookie either since I am not the only person who will be using this page. I'll look into using a DB. Thanks!